# how to easy test a void method in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am new and trying to learn testing in Angular so I need to test this void method which looks hard to me. Can you please help? I have looked in many website, but there are many ways. Which is the best for a novice?

```
 submitForm(): void {
    this.authService.playerName = this.userName.nativeElement.value;
    if (this.login()) {
        if (this.inputMulti.nativeElement.checked) {
            this.openMulti();
        } else if (this.inputSolo) {
            this.closePop();
            this.router.navigate(['/game']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit testing is all about forcing your code to make sure it takes a certain path and when it takes that path, to make sure things are as expected. A unit test comprises of (1) code that forces the code to take a certain path / branch AND (2) expectations - e.g. `expect(spy).to.notHaveBeenCalled()` OR `expect(a).toStictEqual(1)`

Your main tools are:

stubs: Methods that, within the test suite, are called instead of the real method that they are stubbing.

spies: Spies do the same as stubs but more. Spies not only allow you to return different values. They also allow you to check whether a method was called, how many times it was called, what values were passed to the method when it was called, etc.

The idea here is that you only want to test the code within the `submitForm` method that you are testing AND NOT ANY CODE outside that method. Think of `submitForm` as the unit that you are testing.

I'm not going to write the code for you because I don't have the time but here's the basic approach you want to take.

Firstly, you want to test all code paths, you have a total of 4:

**code path 1: does not enter the top level IF statement**

Here, you need to create a spy / stub. Your test will replace the real `this.login` method (within your test suite only - no need to change the code you are testing) with the spy / stub. The spy / stub of the `this.login` method must return false. In this test you will expect that `openMulti` was NOT called and `closePop` was NOT called. You will need to spy on both these methods to make sure they were NOT called.

**code path 2: enters the top level IF statement and executes the IF branch of the nested IF statement**

Here you need to spy / stub `this.login` again - this time forcing it to return true. You will need to initialise the value of `this.inputMulti.nativeElement.checked` to be true (within your test suite). And you will expect `this.openMulti` to have been called.

**code path 3: enters the top level IF statement and executes the ELSE IF branch of the nested IF statement**

Similar approach to (2) but here you will want to make sure `this.inputMulti.nativeElement.checked` is false and `this.inputSolo` is true. You will expect that the router will call the `navigate` method and `closePop` is called. You may even want to go as far as testing that `openMulti` was NOT called.

**code path 4: enters the top level IF statement and does NOT execute any of the branches in the nested IF statement**

Same approach as before. Expect nothing to be called.

Sadly, there is no easy approach with unit testing. You just have to dive in, feel the pain and get used to the thinking behind it and how to write the code. Plenty of useful tutorials out there for the latter. This answer focuses more on the thinking.

If you are using `istanbul` (you are probably using it under the hood) then enable coverage. It will create a coverage folder. In this coverage folder you will find an HTML file that you can right click and open in browser and which shows which code paths / branches have been tested (and which have not).

All the best.

Comment: thanks for accepting - one thing i forgot to mention that is not relevant to the function you are testing - if the code you are testing contains HTTP calls then there will be a tool to mock the http response - its neither a spy nor a stub but rather it intercepts the HTTP call and returns the response you want - again to force the code to take a certain path